# Selecting the row with the max in a column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table called MyTable

```
    First     Second     Third    Fourth
    1         Ab         Cd       2.3
    1         Cq         Fe       3.4
    2         Dr         Dh       1.2
    3         Bb         Qd       9.8
   ..........ETC.....................
```

How can I select the rows grouped by First that have a maximum `Fourth` column value. So it would be a query that results in

```
    First     Second     Third    Fourth
    1         Cq         Fe       3.4
    2         Dr         Dh       1.2
    3         Bb         Qd       9.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
select MT.First, MT.Second, MT.Third, MT.Fourth 
from MyTable MT
join ( select first, max(Fourth) as Fourth
       from MyTable
       group by first
     ) T on T.first = MT.First
         and T.Fourth = MT.Fourth
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a81d/1/0) Demo

Comment: but now there are two rows with the first value being "1"

Comment: @CodeGuy Really? I tested it and  it works correctly. I added sql fiddle.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
select * 
from   MyTable T
join      (Select First,max(Fourth) as Fourth
          from MyTable
          group by First)a
on    T.First=a.First
and   T.Fourth=a.Fourth
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0b66/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    B.*
from (select T.First, max(T.Fourth) as Fourth from Table as T) as A
    inner join Table as B on B.First = B.First and B.Fourth = A.Fourth
```