# I am stuck on one query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck on one query in mysql.

I want to fetch most recent comment from the table

- the comment should be most recent comment on the blog
- the blogs should be latest 3 blogs.
- display comment & blog only if their status is Enabled

records should be like this
[image]
[image]
[image]
Table Structure for the table  the table **blog**

---

```
  
blog_id int - primary (auto increment)
blog_title       -varchar
blog_desc        -varchar
blog_image       -varchar
blog_tags        -varchar
tot_comments     -int
blog_creater     -varchar
blog_create_date -datetime
blog_status      -enum ('Enable','Disable')
```

table structure for the table **blog_comment**

---

```
comment_id       -int (auto increment)  
fk_blog_id       -int  
comment          -varchar  
comment_by       -varchar  
email            -varchar  
comment_date     -datetime  
comment_status   -enum ('Enable','Disable')
```

And below is query written by me, but the result I am getting is wrong.

```
SELECT b.blog_title,b.blog_image, bc.*
FROM blog_comments  bc, blog b
WHERE bc.comment_status='Enable'
AND b.blog_status='Enable'
AND b.blog_id=bc.fk_blog_id
GROUP BY bc.fk_blog_id    
ORDER BY bc.comment_date DESC 
LIMIT 0,3
```

**Output**

---

[image]

Comment: +1 for the way you presented the problem; very clean description

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian: Indeed, except the title that is...

Comment: the group by groups all results from that certain blog into one single row; therefor you are not getting a list of all comments..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting the row with the max in a column - MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064114/selecting-the-row-with-the-max-in-a-column-mysql)

Comment: do you want to generate result for blog post and that's corresponding comments in a single query? if so then please provide "create" statement for this two table. I want to create the tables.

Comment: +7? For what is basically a FAQ? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this the easy solution will be execute 2 query for your result . first query get blog post result

```
$db_blog="select blog_id,blog_title from blog where blog_ststus='Enable'";
$que=mysql_query($db_blog); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($que))
{
    echo $row->blog_title;
    $db_comment="select comment from blog_comments where fk_blog_id=".$row->blog_id." and comment_status='Enable' order by comment_date desc";
    $quec=mysql_query($db_comment);
    while($comment=mysql_fetch_object($quec))
    {
         echo $comment->comment;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's worked !! thank you very much. but do you know how get result from one query

Comment: You should not put a query inside a while loop.
This can be very dangerous and kill performance.

For each result from the first query you will be firing a new query. If the first query returns 9 results you will be executing 9 extra queries. Using 2 queries is not a but option but remove the second query outside of the while loop, and make use of the results from the 1st query!

Comment: @AlpeshTrivedi I'll try to make it in single query. If I success then I will post it in here.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.blog_title,b.blog_image, bc.*
FROM blog b
left join (
Select * from 
blog_comments bc
WHERE bc.comment_status='Enable'
GROUP BY bc.fk_blog_id    
having max(bc.comment_date) =  bc.comment_date
) bcc on b.blog_id=bcc.fk_blog_id
where
b.blog_status='Enable'
ORDER BY b.blog_create_date desc
LIMIT 0,3
```

Try this one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_comments  bc, blog b
WHERE `bc.comment_status`='Enable'
AND `b.blog_status`='Enable'
AND `b.blog_id`=bc.fk_blog_id
ORDER BY `bc.comment_date` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Try a simpler one:

```
SELECT * FROM `blog_comment` WHERE 'blog_status'='Enable' AND 'blog_id'='$blogidherefromtitle' ORDER BY 'comment_date' DESC LIMIT1
```

Comment: blog table is missing in this query... :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT b.blog_title,b.blog_image, bc.*
FROM blog_comments AS bc, blog AS b
WHERE bc.comment_status='Enable'
AND b.blog_status='Enable'
AND b.blog_id=bc.fk_blog_id
GROUP BY bc.fk_blog_id    
ORDER BY bc.comment_date DESC 
LIMIT 0,3;
```

(I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: I figured the "AS" was the problem. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.blog_title,b.blog_image, bc.*
FROM blog_comments  bc JOIN blog b ON bc.fk_blog_id = b.blog_id
WHERE bc.comment_status='Enable'
AND b.blog_status='Enable'
GROUP BY bc.fk_blog_id    
ORDER BY bc.comment_date DESC 
LIMIT 0,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
  bc.* 
FROM
  blog AS b 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT id , MAX(id) AS MaxID FROM blog) AS bl ON bl.id = b.id 
  LEFT JOIN blog_comment AS bc ON bc.fk_blog_id = b.id 
ORDER BY bc.comment_id DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

EDITS:

```
SELECT 
  bc.* 
FROM
  blog AS b 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT id , MAX(id) AS MaxID FROM blog GROUP BY id) AS bl ON bl.id = b.id 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) , fk_blog_id FROM blog_comment  GROUP BY id) AS bc ON bc.fk_blog_id = b.id 
ORDER BY bc.comment_id DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

This is for 3 latest blogs and latest single comments for each blog

Here using inner join will fetch the latest blog. than join comments and order them with date or id and limit them according to your requirements.

Comment: thanks but this one is giving error : #1054 - Unknown column 'bl.MAX' in 'on clause'

#1054 - Unknown column 'bl.MAX' in 'on clause'

Comment: thank you and I have tried but getting wrong output. It fetches only comments of fk_blog_id = 3

Comment: @AlpeshTrivedi than what do you want? that's exactly what my query is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.blog_title, b.blog_image, bc.*
from blog b join
(select bc.*
 from bc join (select fk_blog_id, max(comment_date) latest_date
               from blog_comment
               where comment_status = 'Enable'
               group by fk_blog_id) latest
 on bc.fk_blog_id = latest.fk_blog_id and bc.comment_date = latest_date) c
on b.blog_id = c.fk_blog_id
where b.blog_status = 'Enable'
order by c.comment_date desc
limit 0, 3
```

The `c` subquery finds the row with the latest comment for each blog, using the technique in the linked question. This is then joined with the `blog` table to get the appropriate blog data.

Comment: Fixed it. It's called `c` at that part of the query.